# How do I disable "missing docstring" warnings at a file-level in Pylint?

Tags: python, pylint, docstring

Pylint throws errors that some of the files are missing docstrings. I try and add docstrings to each class, method and function, but it seems that Pylint also checks that files should have a docstring at the beginning of them. Can I disable this somehow?

I would like to be notified of a docstring is missing inside a class, function or method, but it shouldn't be mandatory for a file to have a docstring.

(Is there a term for the legal jargon often found at the beginning of a proprietary source file? Any examples? I don't know whether it is a okay to post such a trivial question separately.)

Answer (score 205, accepted):

It is nice for a Python module to have a docstring, explaining what the module does, what it provides, examples of how to use the classes. This is different from the comments that you often see at the beginning of a file giving the copyright and license information, which IMO should not go in the docstring (some even argue that they should disappear altogether, see e.g. *[Get Rid of Source Code Templates](http://hackerboss.com/get-rid-of-templates/)*)

With Pylint 2.4 and above, you can differentiate between the various `missing-docstring` by using the three following sub-messages:

- `C0114` (`missing-module-docstring`)
- `C0115` (`missing-class-docstring`)
- `C0116` (`missing-function-docstring`)

So the following `.pylintrc` file should work:

```
[MASTER]
disable=
    C0114, # missing-module-docstring
```

For previous versions of Pylint, it does not have a separate code for the various place where docstrings can occur, so all you can do is disable *C0111*. The problem is that if you disable this at module scope, then it will be disabled everywhere in the module (i.e., you won't get any C line for missing function / class / method docstring. Which arguably is not nice.

So I suggest adding that small missing docstring, saying something like:

```
"""
high level support for doing this and that.
"""
```

Soon enough, you'll be finding useful things to put in there, such as providing examples of how to use the various classes / functions of the module which do not necessarily belong to the individual docstrings of the classes / functions (such as how these interact, or something like a quick start guide).

Comment: +1 for legal (and other) boilerplate disappearing from source code. Every component of a car does not have legal notifications attached. By all means create a file with your project's legal text in it. Don't put copies of that into every file.

Comment: Disappointing answer. Especially for Django projects. forms.py "These are models...JUST KIDDING! They're forms. Because, you know, the file is named forms.py. This isn't the The Da Vinci Code. What did you think would be here?"

Comment: `$ cat my_module/test/__init__.py` `"Hey, PyLint? SHUT UP"`

Comment: Pylint says *`String statement has no effect (pointless-string-statement)`* when using your docstring example.

Comment: The most important thing documentation needs to tell you is *why* a function is needed.   If that's all your documentation does, then it's often good enough.   The second most useful thing is "how"  ... (recursive,  thread-unsafe, hits the network api hard, etc.).   The least important things is "what" it does .. this should be clear from the name and the associated unit tests and how clean and readably it's written.  

But, just remember "why first" and you'll know all you need to know about documentation.

Answer (score 114):

As mentioned by [followben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/840428/followben) in the comments, a better solution is to just disable the rules that we want to disable rather than using `--errors-only`. This can be done with `--disable=<msg ids>, -d <msg ids>`.

The list of message IDs can be found [here](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/messages_overview.html). For the specific error mentioned in the question, the message ID is `C0111`.

For using `--disable=` param in your choise of IDE or Text Editor, you will need to figure out how to do it.

For VS Code, this can be done by adding this in `settings.json`:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--disable=C0111"]
```

Comment: It's useful, though `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--disable=C0111"],` is probably moreso as it just quiets docstring warnings. However setting addresses the OP's question of how to disable these warnings only at a module level.

Comment: So sad when I see a project that has resorted to this.   pylint is such a good tool for keeping code clean.   It just needs some love.

Comment: Nice fix but the downside to this method is it ignores unused variables

Comment: @EricDuminil, thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the answer to specify that the mentioned solution is IDE / Text Editor specifc.

Comment: python.linting has been deprecated. Instead you should do the following
"pylint.args": [
        "--disable=missing-class-docstring",
        "--disable=missing-function-docstring",
        "--disable=missing-module-docstring"
    ],

Answer (score 23):

Just put the following lines at the beginning of any file you want to disable these warnings for.

```
# pylint: disable=missing-module-docstring
# pylint: disable=missing-class-docstring
# pylint: disable=missing-function-docstring
```

Comment: If you want to disable everything you just need to disable `missing-docstring` (works for version prior to 2.4.0).

Comment: Wait, what? If you don't want to litter your code with uninformative docstrings, your solution is to litter them with boilerplate comments?

Answer (score 17):

I just wanted to add to what [@Milovan Tomašević](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13155046/milovan-toma%c5%a1evi%c4%87) posted above.  I decided to use `python.linting.pylintArgs` in VSCode's [global settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations), as it was far more convenient than using a `.pylintrc` file.
Also, instead of using an ID for the switch (such as `C0115`), I used the symbolic names instead.

Full reference to [Pylint options and switches is here](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html).

```json
{
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=missing-class-docstring",
        "--disable=missing-function-docstring"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I came looking for an answer because, as [cerin said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877522/how-do-i-disable-missing-docstring-warnings-at-a-file-level-in-pylint#comment13063082_7878690), in Django projects it is cumbersome and redundant to add module docstrings to every one of the files that Django automatically generates when creating a new application.

So, as a workaround for the fact that Pylint doesn't let you specify a difference in docstring types, you can do this:

```
pylint */*.py --msg-template='{path}: {C}:{line:3d},{column:2d}: {msg}' | grep docstring | grep -v module
```

You have to update the msg-template, so that when you grep you will still know the file name. This returns all the other missing-docstring types excluding modules.

Then you can fix all of those errors, and afterwards just run:

```
pylint */*.py --disable=missing-docstring
```

Answer (score 12):

With Pylint 2.4 and above you can differentiate between the various `missing-docstring` by using the three following sub-messages:

- `C0114` (`missing-module-docstring`)
- `C0115` (`missing-class-docstring`)
- `C0116` (`missing-function-docstring`)

So the following `.pylintrc` file should work:

```
[MASTER]
disable=
    C0114, # missing-module-docstring
```

Answer (score 12):

In my case, with Pylint 2.6.0, the missing docstring messages wouldn't disappear, even after explicitly disabling `missing-module-docstring`, `missing-class-docstring` and `missing-function-docstring` in my `.pylintrc` file. Finally, the following configuration worked for me:

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]

disable=missing-docstring,empty-docstring
```

Apparently, Pylint 2.6.0 still validates docstrings unless both checks are disabled.

Answer (score 11):

I think the fix is relative easy without disabling this feature.

```
def kos_root():
    """Return the pathname of the KOS root directory."""
    global _kos_root
    if _kos_root: return _kos_root
```

All you need to do is add the triple double quotes string in every function.

Comment: well it's still annoying for example if you working on a Django project it will create a bunch of module files and you have to go into each one of those to do it.It's better to only show error message than warning with ""--errors-only" in the pylint user settings

Answer (score 7):

**No.** Pylint doesn't currently let you discriminate between doc-string warnings.

However, you can use [Flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/index.html) for all Python code checking along with the doc-string extension to ignore this warning.

Install the doc-string extension with pip (internally, it uses [pydocstyle](http://www.pydocstyle.org/en/latest/index.html)).

```
pip install flake8_docstrings
```

You can then just use the `--ignore D100` switch. For example, `flake8 file.py --ignore D100`

Answer (score 6):

If you are a ***Visual Studio Code*** user who wants to ignore this, you can add `python.linting.pylintArgs` to `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=C0114",
        "--disable=C0115",
        "--disable=C0116",
    ],
    ...
}
```

Comment: It looks like `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--disable=C0114,C0115,C0116"]` is also accepted.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using VSCode (1.78.0) and it looks like they changed the parameters.
You should use

```
"pylint.args": [
"--disable=C0116",
"--disable=C0111",
"--disable=C0114"
```

]

Comment: python isn't a builtin VS Code extension. Likely the change you see is tied to an update in one of the Python extensions instead of VS Code itself. A link to an issue ticket / PR would be nice.

Answer (score 5):

Edit file "C:\Users\Your User\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json" and add these `python.linting.pylintArgs` lines at the end as shown below:

```
{
    "team.showWelcomeMessage": false,
    "python.dataScience.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow": true,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "powershell.codeFormatting.useCorrectCasing": true,
    "files.autoSave": "onWindowChange",
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins=pylint_django",
        "--errors-only"
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Then type and click on > preferences:configure language specific settings
3. and then type "python" after that. Paste the code

   ```
    {
        "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
            "--load-plugins=pylint_django", "--errors-only"
        ],
    }
   ```

Comment: This works for me. Try reloading the vscode.

Answer (score 2):

Open User Settings(JSON) and copy and paste the following lines in between the the curly braces, then save and exit the file.

```
"pylint.args": [
    "disable=missing-module-docstring",
    "disable=missing-class-docstring",
    "disable=missing-function-docstring"
]
```

This worked for me out of the above solution.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find this anywhere and this is the only thing that actually worked. I searched in settings for pylint and noticed the syntax looked different that was was being explained in comments here. This is my exact user > settings.json file and how I was able to get it so no linting errors showed for docs-strings in VS Code.

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default High Contrast",
    "editor.fontSize": 15,
    "debug.console.fontSize": 16,
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 16,
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "bash",
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.tabSize": 4
      },
      "pylint.args": [
        "--disable=missing-class-docstring",
        "--disable=missing-function-docstring",
        "--disable=missing-module-docstring"
      ]
}
```

After changing that file I did a CMD+shift+P and search for Developer reload window and did a reload of VS code. Save your python file, and you should not see the linting error for doc string.

Answer (score 0):

Go to file "settings.json" and disable the Python `pydocstyle`:

```
"python.linting.pydocstyleEnabled": false
```

Comment: I believe you should also mention what that code snippet you share for the `settings.json` is meant for? For those of you wondering, it's for VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

For `ruff` users that would be

```
[lint]
select = ["D"] # enable docstring checks in ruff
ignore = ["D100"] # ignore missing module docstring
```

inside your `ruff.toml` file.

Comment: Inside `[lint]` or `[tool.ruff.lint]`? The name spacing of the configs is confusing.

Comment: I think it should be `[lint]` if you're using `ruff.toml` for config and `[tool.ruff.lint]` if you're using `pyproject.toml` for config.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I like to have total control on where and when I put my docstrings without having VSCode (or any IDE / code editor) throw visual chaos at me - hence I have simply inserted

```
[pylint.messages control]
disable = missing-docstring
```

in my .pylintrc file. This file is not committed e.g. part of gitignore - hence each team member working on the project can have their own setting. This only works if there is already a standard that the project adheres to (else everyone will be doing their own thing with these comments and docstrings and its chaos) - so make sure you know what you're doing before using this setup. works with teams that have been working together for a long time and who adhere to internal standards on how to write code for the project.