# Check that a Python project is properly documented

Tags: python, python-3.x, checkstyle, docstring

I have a bunch of Python v3.6 projects.
I am using codestyle to check that they are PEP8 compliant.

Is there a way to use codestyle (or any other tool) to check that all functions, classes and methods in my modules are documented (i.e., have an associated docstring)?

Comment: See [How do I disable “missing docstring” warnings at a file-level in Pylint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877522/how-do-i-disable-missing-docstring-warnings-at-a-file-level-in-pylint)

Comment: Thank you very much, Pylint seems perfect :)