# Disabling Pylint warnings in VSCode Version 1.74 not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint

I am using **VSCode 1.74** (the latest at the time of writing), and I am trying to disable some linting warnings in Pylint globally.
The warnings are:

1. `Missing module docstringpylint(missing-module-docstring - C0114)`
2. `Missing class docstringpylint(missing-class-docstring - C0115)`
3. `Missing function docstringpylint(missing-function-docstring - C0116)`

So as per the other answers on this site, I have tried adding the `python.linting.pylintArgs` in `settings.json` found in `"Preferences:Open User Settings(JSON)"` as shown below, but none is working out for me:

`method 1`

```json
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=missing-module-docstring",
        "--disable=missing-class-docstring",
        "--disable=missing-function-docstring"
      ]
```

`method 2`

```json
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=C0111"
    ]
```

`method 3`

```json
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=C0114",
        "--disable=C0115",
        "--disable=C0116"
    ]
```

But the warnings still persist.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please check my answer in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76203055/6272980